# Как получить максимальную позицию полосы прокрутки по Y-координате?

Tags: javascript, html

Как получить максимальную позицию полосы прокрутки по **Y-координате**?

Это почему-то выдает на 600-700px (зависит от браузера) больше:

```
 var scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

---

**Ну неужели никто не знает !?** =)

---

Ладно, если все затрудняются ответить, то попробую переформулировать вопрос. Как определить, что страница полностью прокручена, т.е пользователь прокрутил весь скрол и сейчас в самом низу страницы?

Comment: Help me somebody!

Answer (score 1):

Может эта [ссылка](http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html) поможет?

Вообще получаем scrollTop + window.innerHeight и сравниваем с document.clientHeight если >= то по идее в самом конце. За синтаксис window, document могу ошибаться, если пройти по ссылки там нарисованы методы точно.